# Azure Devops SSH Deployment Task Inline Script Hang Problem

Tags: ssh, azure-devops

When I want to run a script in Inline Script mode on SSH Deployment Task on Azure Devops Version Dev17.M153.5, that one goes on hang as below. There is no problem that we have checked the authorizations of the user running the command. Operating system version on target Solaris 11.4.Is there a method to solve this problem?

##[debug]inline=cd  /home/userstfs/workspaces/*****/src;pwd

##[debug]No script header detected.  Adding: #!/bin/bash

##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=D:****_temp

##[debug]failOnStdErr=true

Trying to establish an SSH connection to ********@**.***.***.***:22

Successfully connected.

**##[debug]remoteScriptPath = "./sshscript_1596017258623._unix"**

**##[debug]Copying script to remote machine**

Comment: If you run a simple command instead of inline script, how's the result? Did you try to create a new SSH key pair? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the agent in the deployment pools from:
Organization setting - Deployment pools - Update targets

[image: see the attached image]

Comment: This only applies to classic Release Pipelines